# HTML Canvas javascript move object on Z axis

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a 3D like effect in HTML Canvas. I want to have the effect of a 2D object coming towards the first person view. Is there a way to make it look like a rectangle is moving on the Z axis?

This is my code. I sort of have what I want but it does not really look natural.

Use the up arrow key to move the object. You can also use the left and right arrow keys to move it to the left and right.

I am trying to make a game similar to this game: http://game.notch.net/christmaschopping/

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canv');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

window.onload = function() {
    start();
    setInterval(update, 10);
}

class Obstacle {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = 30;
        this.h = 60;
        this.xSpeed = 0;
        this.ySpeed = 0;
        this.passedView = false;
        this.zSpeed = 0;
    }
    show() {
        if (!this.passedView) {
            c.fillStyle = 'green';
            c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        }
    }
    update() {
        this.x += this.xSpeed;
        this.y += this.ySpeed;

        this.w+=this.zSpeed;
        this.h+=this.zSpeed;
        this.x-=this.zSpeed/2;
        this.y-=this.zSpeed/2;
    }
}

var ob;

function start() {
    ob = new Obstacle(385, 370);
}

function update() {
    //background
    c.fillStyle = 'lightblue';
    c.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);
    //obstacle
    ob.show();
    ob.update();
}

function keyDown(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 39:
            ob.xSpeed = 5;
            break;
        case 37:
            ob.xSpeed = -5;
            break;
        case 38:
            ob.zSpeed = 5;
            break;
    }
}

function keyUp(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 39:
            ob.xSpeed = 0;
            break;
        case 37:
            ob.xSpeed = 0;
            break;
        case 38:
            ob.zSpeed = 0;
            break;
    }
}

document.onkeydown = keyDown;
document.onkeyup = keyUp;
```

```html
<canvas id='canv' width=800 height=800></canvas>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: "I sort of have what I want but it does not really look natural". You are going to have to explain what you mean by "natural".

Comment: I would take a look at three js https://threejs.org/

Comment: I mean that it does not look like it is coming towards the view, it looks like it is just getting bigger, which is not what I want.

Comment: Hi Luke, from what I'm seeing, you are a long way from creating anything 3D in HTML. You will need to dive into 2D and 3D math, matrix manipulation, perspective, camera, to name a few. Before anything, do some reading [introduction to CSS 3D transforms](https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/) and its code on [Github](https://github.com/desandro/3dtransforms).

Comment: I am only trying to move a rectangle, drawn onto a canvas with JavaScript, on the Z axis, to make the effect of a rectangle coming towards the view

Comment: I am trying to make a game similar to this one: http://game.notch.net/christmaschopping/

Comment: @lukescodingnice - that game you've shown is using webGL. One of the users here, gman, has written a bunch of (fantastic) articles discussing its use. https://stackoverflow.com/users/128511/gman

Comment: I know, I just want to know a way to make it look like something is moving on the Z axis, do I scale up the object, do I move it on the Y axis, what do I do?

Comment: @lukescodingnice - you implement the perspective transform. The X/Y screen coord is found by dividing the world X/Y pos by the world Z. That way objects get larger and move as we'd expect. The key, is the divide by Z step.

Answer (score 0):

its hard to perceive 3D looking a one object so give yourself several objects moving independently ... let the objects move on their own

I suggest you introduce the notion of perspective projection ... its why objects moving away get smaller

to keep it simple assign objects a size then scale that size using their Z dimension location

in addition to giving each object a location in 3d ( x,y,z ) put all of them inside a world say the inside of a cube or a sphere

launch each new object in some random direction at a random speed, random size

put all objects into some datastructure so you have an array you can iterate across to do things to each object

introduce the notion of time into this world ... iterate across the datastructure of your objects and perform actions as in

- gently move the x,y,z location of the current object just a tiny bit in each dim ... keep tract of the sign ( pos/neg ) of each increment in each dimension
- if the current x or y or z goes outside the interior of the cube or sphere then toggle the sign of the increment for that dimension as mentioned above
- when you draw a given object scale its size based on its Z dimension ... this is perspective projection

  ```
  object_rendered_size = object_constant_size * Z dimension for this object
  ```
- advance the clock to the next epoch ... put above loop inside an outer loop so everything keeps moving all the time

And yes this will give you 3D ... no need to jump straight into WebGL until after projects like this just code themselves ...  with today's hardware you can go very far using your current approach of using canvas ... teach yourself linear algebra to manipulate object or camera location using matrix mechanics

have Fun !!!